# Global Cache Working too well?

Tags: cache

I have a long entry list of authors and I am using global cache to help with the page load, but this global cache prevents the `if` statement from adding `selected` to the appropriate option. When I remove the global cache everything performs as intended.

```
<select name="filter-by-author" onchange="window.location.href=this.value;">
    <option value="/blog">All Authors</option>
        {% cache globally %}
            {% nav author in craft.users({ group: 'blogAuthors', order: 'firstName', limit: null }) %}
                <option value="{{ url('blog/author/'~author.username) }}"
                {% if craft.request.getLastSegment() == author.username %}selected{% endif %}>
                {{ author.name | title }}
                </option>
            {% endnav %}
        {% endcache %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what caching is supposed to do... flatten the Twig code down to basic HTML, and serve that up instead of dynamically rendering it. Using `globally` means that the HTML would be identical on every page, which is not really what you want here.

Get rid of `globally`, so it can cache separately for each page. Since the URL is supposed to affect how that snippet is rendered, you don't want to cache `globally`.